# Bootstrap : anchor with i class

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, icons, anchor

I'm using twitter Boostrap, my navbar look this way :

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
   <span class="hidden-tablet">MyTitle</span></a>
</li>
```

When I'm trying to replace the href with an anchor, my Bootstrap icon is no longer aligned with MyTitle (not on the same line).

here is what I've tried :

```
<li><?php echo anchor('mycontroler','MyTitle')?><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
   <span class="hidden-tablet"> </span>
</li>
```

Any clues ?

Comment: is anchor() a function you defined or what?

Comment: hum, i forgot to say I'm using CodeIgniter, anchor creates a standard HTML anchor link based the local site URL:

    <a href="http://example.com">Click Here</a>


anchor(uri segments, text, attributes)

Comment: what is the exact html generated from that function?

Comment: <a href="http://127.0.0.1/mywebsitename/index.php/mycontrollername">Mytitle</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second block of code, the icon is outside the anchor tag. To replicate the code from the first block, you shoud have:

```
<li><?php echo anchor('mycontroler','<i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
    <span class="hidden-tablet">MyTitle</span>')?>
</li>
```

This should also solve the alignment issue.

Comment: glad I helped you, ciao :)